# When scanning for a string, how do I not allow input if the user inputs more than 30 characters?

Tags: c

So I have this scanf

```
scanf ("%30[^\n]%c", &i
```

How can I add a condition where if a user inputs more than 30 characters, it prompts a message saying there are too many characters and to get them to reenter?

Here is my entire loop to keep re entering until the input is correct but I don't have the proper condition set

```
int keeptrying = 1, rc;
char after, i;

do
{
    rc = scanf ("%30[^\n]%c", &i, &after);
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            clear();
        }
            else if (after != '\n')
            {
                printf (" **Trailing characters try again: ");
                clear();
            }
                else if () // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD PUT THE CONDITION
                {
                    printf (" **Title is longer than 30 characters: ");
                }
                    else
                    {
                        keeptrying = 0;
                    }

} while (keeptrying == 1);

return i;
```

Comment: [`strlen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html)

Comment: Storing up to 30 characters plus a trailing null into `i` is a *bad idea™*.  You need `i` to be an array of at least 31 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just want to read in a line, and check to see if its length is greater than 30. To do that, you use `strlen()`, to read in the line I'd recommend using something like `getline` instead:

```
int keeptrying = 1;
char *line = NULL;
size_t linecap = 0;

do {
    ssize_t rc = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin);
    if (rc == 0)
    {
        printf ("End of file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (strlen(line) > 30)
    {
        printf (" **Title is longer than 30 characters: ");
    }
    else
    {
        keeptrying = 0;
    }
} while (keeptrying == 1);

// Use line

free(line);
```

Comment: Yeah after trying this it does not work...after some research some of the code you gave me doesn't work in C

Comment: I don't think getline works with my IDE? I don't know, i am having multiple problems when trying to use your code

Comment: @albert Can you give me a specific error? I'd like to fix my answer if I can.

Comment: first getline is giving me problems, i basically can't get that to work. After googling it a bit i had to add some #define blahblah thing before  #include <stdio.h> and that wouldn't work for me because this is a school assignment and have some guidelines and that would not be allowed. Also when compling i had some errors with size_t not being an int or something, also pointer errors and just a lot of errors so I went back to something more similar to my original code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use getchar after scanf (also to clear stdin):

```
do
{
    char i[31];
    rc = scanf ("%30[^\n]", &i);
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            clear();
        }
            else if (getchar() != '\n')
            {
                printf (" more than 30 characters try again: ");
                clear();
            }
                    else
                    {
                        keeptrying = 0;
                    }

} while (keeptrying == 1);
```